# Can not get the property defined in constructor method when write code obeys ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and Node.js, I am trying to write code obeys ECMAScript 6, but I can not get the property define in constructor method, while it can be referenced with the old write style:

```
'use strict'

function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name
}

// Animal.prototype.walk = (destination) => {
//     console.log(this.name + " walk to " + destination)  //undefined walk to China
// }

Animal.prototype.walk = function (destination) {
    console.log(this.name + " walk to " + destination)  //Cat walk to China
}

const cat = new Animal("Cat")
cat.walk('China')

I want to know the reason, thanks!
```

Comment: Non-arrow functions are not the “old style”; they’re a different style, with different `this` rules. Continue using function expressions if you want to attach things to a prototype. `class` also exists in ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] am trying to write code obeys ECMAScript 6, but I can not get the property define in constructor method, while it can be referenced with the old write style

Note that the problem is not your "constructor" that works just fin in either case: it will define a `name` property on the instance.

It's the fact how you access `name` in both the commented and the uncommented `walk()` method.

The arrow function `()=>` isn't shortcut of `function(){}`, it was born for a purpose that avoid defining reference `context` of environment into a `function`.

With your example above, I describe it in ES5:

```
'use strict'

function Animal (name) {
  this.name = name
}


Animal.prototype.walk = (destination) => {
  console.log(this.name + " walk to " + destination)  //undefined walk to China
}

//the above ES6 will be transform to ES5 like this:
var self = this; //reference `this` - the environment context into variable `self`.
Animal.prototype.walk = function(destination) {
  console.log(self.name + " walk to " + destination);
}


const cat = new Animal("Cat")
cat.walk('China'); // undefined walk to China.
```

I hope following the example above, you can learn that what exactly `this` is. So, please use `arrow function` "responsively".

Comment: I wrote an article about scope and context, hope it could help :) https://kaiz.space/scope-and-cotext/

Comment: thank you @try-catch-finally for updating my answer :)